"Enter current password" request on blue screen after update from 22.04 to 24.04
I updated my laptop from 22.04 to 24.04, without any problem / error messages.
After restart I get a "Enter current password" request on the black screen (image attached). Previous root password is not accepted, and there is no way to enter in safe mode. What can I do?


That looks like a BIOS prompt.

You are right David, thank you! I solved the BIOS issue with a bios password recovery tool, but I'm still in trouble because the update to 26.04 made my disk not bootable...

Since 26.04 is almost 5 years away you lost me.
